# How to capture response sent from a website

Tags: java, servlets

I tried to search this topic on the internet but couldn't get any proper solution. I want to open a page through my Servlet and capture response that is received from the server so that I could alter/retrieve the data I get from the response. I am not talking about filtering the data sent from my own servlet but getting the response from other websites.

Any suggested reading would be greatly appreciated.

Basically, I was trying to extract all the hrefs present on a page through FileIO. But that can be a tedious process as I had to download the pages before-hand. 
Also, is there any other way to do this? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or other http client modules

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) and make use of its webdriver api..

> List allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

Or just

```
Pattern linkElementPattern = Pattern.compile(“]*href=\”[^>]*>(.*?)“);
List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
// html is your HTML source String.. 
while (linkElementPattern.matcher(html)) {
       links.add(linkElementMatcher.group());
}
```